# Resource em um enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Tenho um `enum` e gostaria de mudar a `Description` com Resource:

```
public enum SystemArea
{
    [Description("Gestor")]
    Gestor = 3,
    [Description("Administrador")]
    Administrador = 2,
    [Description("Professor | Profesor")]
    Professor = 1,
    [Description("Aluno | Alumno")]
    Aluno = 0,
}
```

Já tentei das seguintes maneiras, mas nenhuma funcionou:
1) Passando o Resource no próprio Description

```
[Description(Resources.DISPLAY_GESTOR)]
Gestor = 3
```

2) Com o Display:

```
[Display(Name = "DISPLAY_GESTOR", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
Gestor = 3
```

Tem alguma forma de resolver?

Comment: Veja isto, te ajuda mais que a resposta que eu postei? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569298/localizing-enum-descriptions-attributes se for o caso, eu atualizo a resposta. Tem esse também: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17380900/221800

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tentei pegar o melhor dos dois mundos:

- [Segunda Resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569298/localizing-enum-descriptions-attributes)
- [Primeira Resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380900/enum-localization)

Então, consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:
De lambuja um método estático para retornar o resource de todos os itens.

```
namespace SeuNamespace
{
    public class Enumeration
    {
        public enum MeuEnum
        {
            [LocalizedEnum("DISPLAY_ITEM1", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
            Item1 = 4,
            [LocalizedEnum("DISPLAY_ITEM2", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
            Item2 = 3,
            [LocalizedEnum("DISPLAY_ITEM3", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
            Item3 = 2
        }

        public static List<string> GetAllEnumDescription()
        {
            List<string> resultado = new List<string>();

            foreach (MeuEnum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MeuEnum)))
            {
                FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

                LocalizedEnumAttribute[] attributes =
                    (LocalizedEnumAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LocalizedEnumAttribute), false);

                if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                    resultado.Add(value.GetLocalizedDescription());
                else
                    resultado.Add(value.ToString());
            }

            return resultado;
        }
    }

    #region EnumAttribute
    public class LocalizedEnumAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
    {
        private PropertyInfo _nameProperty;
        private Type _resourceType;

        public LocalizedEnumAttribute(string displayNameKey)
            : base(displayNameKey)
        {

        }

        public Type ResourceType
        {
            get
            {
                return _resourceType;
            }
            set
            {
                _resourceType = value;

                _nameProperty = _resourceType.GetProperty(this.Description, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            }
        }

        public override string Description
        {
            get
            {
                if (_nameProperty == null)
                {
                    return base.Description;
                }

                return (string)_nameProperty.GetValue(_nameProperty.DeclaringType, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class EnumExtender
    {
        public static string GetLocalizedDescription(this Enum @enum)
        {
            if (@enum == null)
                return null;

            string description = @enum.ToString();

            FieldInfo fieldInfo = @enum.GetType().GetField(description);
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes.Any())
                return attributes[0].Description;

            return description;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Para obter o resource de apenas um item basta: `MeuEnum.Item1.GetLocalizedDescription();`.
Para obter o resource de todos os itens basta: `MeuEnum.GetAllEnumDescription();`.
Testado e aprovado. Seja feliz!

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma de resolver é criar um método de extensão, que caso não exista um resource, devolva o próprio item do enum:

```
public static class SystemAreaExtension
{
  public static string Display(this SystemArea value) {
    var compare = new ResourceManager("SystemArea", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                    .GetString("SystemArea_" + value);
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(compare) ? value : compare;
  }
}
```

Ou genérico:

```c#
public static class EnumExtension {
  public static string Display(this Enum item) {
    var compare = new ResourceManager("SystemArea", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                  .GetString(item.GetType().Name + "_" + item);
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(compare) ? item.ToString() : compare;
  }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YZSLA8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAn2Hc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/Resource.cs).

Obviamente os recursos precisam ser colocadas desta forma. Mas pode ser adaptado ao que precisa.

Comment: Acho que apenas a segunda já responderia bem. +1.

Comment: É a que eu usaria. Mas tem gente que pode querer fazer algo diferente dependendo do tipo.