# Conversão de enum para string

Tags: c#, json, enums

Boa tarde!

Estou com a seguinte situação, como retorno de uma requisição recebo um json com diversas informações. No c# converto estas informações para objetos utilizando o JsonConvert.Deserialize()..

Olhe o retorno abaixo:

```
{
"id": "AV654AS65D4AS654DASD65AS4DA6S5D4AS65D4",
"due_date": "2017-08-10",
"currency": "BRL",
"items_total_cents": 1800,
"status": "paid",
"updated_at": "2017-08-11T10:45:30-03:00",
"total_cents": 1800,
"total_paid_cents": 1620,
"paid_at": "2017-08-11T10:45:30-03:00",
"taxes_paid_cents": 128,
"paid_cents": 1620,
"payable_with": "bank_slip",
"paid": "R$ 16,20",
"transaction_number": 9999999999,
"payment_method": "bank_slip",
"created_at_iso": "2017-08-10T11:25:46-03:00",
"updated_at_iso": "2017-08-11T10:45:30-03:00",
"items": [
  {
    "id": "AV654AS65D4AS654DASD65AS4DA6S5D4AS65D4",
    "description": "PARCELA X Y Z",
    "price_cents": 1800,
    "quantity": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-08-10T11:25:46-03:00",
    "updated_at": "2017-08-10T11:25:46-03:00",
    "price": "R$ 18,00"
  }
],
"variables": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "variable": "payment_data.bank",
    "value": "bradesco"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "variable": "payment_data.occurrence_date",
  "value": "100817"
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "variable": "payment_data.transaction_identifier",
  "value": "110817027400"
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "variable": "payment_data.transaction_number",
  "value": "90801863"
},
{
  "id": "5",
  "variable": "payment_method",
  "value": "iugu_bank_slip"
}
]
}
```

Em **variables** tenho a seguinte estrutura: id, variable e value.
O campo variable possui valores pré-definidos, conseguiria converter estes valores para algo semelhante a enum? o C# oferece esta brecha?

tipo:

```
EnumString{
 payment_data.bank,
 payment_data.occurrence_date, 
 payment_data.transaction_identifier,
 payment_data.transaction_number,
 payment_method
}
```

Comment: Já pesquisei várias vezes sobre isso e até então não encontrei nenhuma forma _automática_ pra fazer isso; é preciso converter o valor que você tem no correspondente ao _enum_.
Normalmente atribuo um `DefaultValue` para o _enum_ e crio classe/método de conversão pra comparar os valores e retornar o _enum_ correspondente.

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123841/101 Ou isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82946/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eu utilizo a seguinte função para informar uma string e retornar o Enum:

```
public static T GetEnum<T>(string s)
{
    Array arr = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
    foreach (var x in arr)
    {
        if (x.ToString().Contains(s))
            return (T)x;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

no código, estou utilizando o `Contains`, mas você pode fazer a comparação que for melhor pra você.

Comment: Valeu! Fiz o seguinte:
        public string variable
        {
            set
            {
                variavel = GetEnum<EnumVars>(value.Replace('.','_'));
            }
        }
        public EnumVars variavel;

No fim converte corretamente as variáveis para os respectivos enums.