# Como eu posso usar ou nomear constantes para campos de tipo resposta?

Tags: c#, estilo-de-codificação, convenções-de-nome, constantes

Há situações no qual temos campos que representam um tipo de resposta, seja repostas booleanas `sim` e `não`, `S` e `N` ou com múltiplas respostas como o status de algo. Por exemplo o status da analise de um certificado de um curso fornecido por alguma instituição:

1. Certificado sim `S`
2. Certificado não `N`
3. Certificado em analise `A`

Considerando o contexto acima, o uso de *constante* pode ser adotado para facilitar a leitura do código.

Agora veja um exemplo real da classe `Instituicao` que possui campos de tipo resposta no qual esta usando constantes para eles:

```
public class Instituicao
{
    public static string DeletadoSim { get; } = "S";
    public static string DeletadoNao { get; } = "N";
    public static string AtivaSim { get; } = "S";
    public static string AtivaNao { get; } = "N";
    public static string CertificadoDisponivel { get; } = "S";
    public static string CertificadoNaoDisponivel { get; } = "N";
    public static string CertificadoEmAnalise { get; } = "A";

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public string UrlSite { get; set; }
    public string Ativa { get; set; } = AtivaSim;
    public string TemCertificadoGratuito { get; set; }
    public string Deletado { get; set; } = DeletadoNao;
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public List<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}
```

Assim sendo, o cenário que foi ilustrado acima me deixou com dúvidas em relação a nomeação e criação de constantes.

## Dúvidas

1. Em casos assim, devemos utilizar constantes? Há outra alternativa?
   Se sim, quais?
2. No caso de constantes, como eu poderia nomeá-las afim de evitar a prolixidade, redundância ou qualquer coisa que não deixe o código limpo para campos de tipo resposta?

Comment: Como assim constantes ?  tipo public const int c1 = 5;

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes acho que eu poderia colocar um exemplo de uso para ficar fácil o entendimento.

Comment: Todo programador é familiarizado com o tipo booliano, para dois status mutuamente exclusivos o uso de booliano basta. A enumeração usa-se para designar mais de dois status (não necessáriamente mutuamente exclusivos com o uso do atributo [Flags]). O tipo subjacente inteiro deriva dos primórdios da programação de microcontroladores, quando se tinha pouca memória e um número baixo de instruções por segundo, assim poderia-se comparar inteiros em uma única instrução. Hoje com máquinas de Ghz e TB de memória isso não é mais um problema.

Comment: Esse tipo de roteamento pode ser feito com um dicionário sem afetar muito sua performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Em casos assim, devemos utilizar constantes? Há outra alternativa? Se sim, quais?

Não fiquei muito fã disto. Parece `Zero = 0` ou `Um = 1`. Se são constantes mesmo porque não colocá-las como constantes?

```
public const string DeletadoSim = "S";
public const string DeletadoNao = "N";
public const string AtivaSim = "S";
public const string AtivaNao = "N";
public const string CertificadoDisponivel = "S";
public const string CertificadoNaoDisponivel = "N";
public const string CertificadoEmAnalise = "A";
```

> No caso de constantes, como eu poderia nomeá-las afim de evitar a prolixidade, redundância ou qualquer coisa que não deixe o código limpo para campos de tipo resposta?

Novamente, me parece tão desnecessário...

Se é para fazer assim , eu prefiro até usar um `enum` que é uma constantes feita para isto. Aumenta a verbosidade, mas se é para dar legibilidade...

```
public enum Deletado { [Display("N")]Nao, [Display("S")]Sim }
public enum Certificado { [Display("N")]NaoDisponivel, [Display("S")]Disponivel, [Display("A")]EmAnalise }
```

Usando:

```
public Deletado Deletado { get; set; } = Deletado.Nao;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/Display.cs).

Obviamente que se precisa do valor com texto terá que tratar isto, provavelmente com uma [função própria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82949/101), dá mais trabalho. Mas eu acho tudo isso exagerado mesmo.

Pena o `enum` não permitir `string` como tipo subjacente (não usar um tipo numérico como tipo da enumeração).

leia mais sobre a semântica mais correta para `enum` em [Uma enumeração deve ser constante no tempo de vida da solução?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21997/101). Para tudo tem exceção. Estamos falando de algo que é complicado lidar quando envolve versionamento. Por isso eu sou crítico de algumas metodologias que pregam fazer o que precisa e depois acha uma solução se algo der errado. Dica: quase todas que são usadas hoje em dia pregam isso, mesmo que algumas neguem.

Quanto ao nome, não tem muito o que fazer, pode deixar só `Sim` e `Nao` na constante, mas perde legibilidade.

Pode ajudar: [Constante é realmente útil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203151/101).

Comment: @gato Obviamente um erro de digitação. Melhorei a explicação. E um erro no uso que esqueci de mudar.

Answer (score 2):

> Em casos assim, devemos utilizar constantes?

Acredito que não. ["As constantes são campos cujos valores são definidos em tempo de compilação e nunca podem ser alterados."](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-constants).

Um exemplo de constante é PI, onde sempre que precisar, você sabe que se chamar `Math.PI` vai ter o valor necessário.

No seu caso específico, o nome da constante está sendo mais significativo que o próprio valor dela.

> Há outra alternativa? Se sim, quais?

Sim. Algumas situações me parecem ser resolvidas apenas com bool: é Ativo ou Inativo; Foi Deletado, ou não. (*Esse ponto também poderia ser resolvido com enum, pois entendo que Se está Ativo ou Inativo não está Deletado, e se está Deletado não está Ativo ou Inativo...*)

Resolvendo com [enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types):

> "Um tipo de enumeração (também chamado de uma enumeração ou enum) fornece uma maneira eficiente para definir um conjunto de constantes integrais nomeadas que podem ser atribuídas a um valor"

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
public enum StatusCertificados
{
     Disponivel,
     NaoDisponivel,
     EmAnalise
}

public enum StatusInstituicoes
{
     Ativo,
     Inativo,
     Deletado
}

public class Instituicao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public StatusInstituicoes Status {get;set;}
    public StatusCertificados CertificadoStatus {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

No objeto:

```
Instituicao obj = new Instituicao();
obj.CertificadoStatus = StatusCertificados.EmAnalise;
obj.Status = StatusInstituicoes.Ativo;

//...


if (obj.Status == StatusInstituicoes.Ativo)
{
 //...
}

//...


if (obj.CertificadoStatus == StatusCertificados.Disponivel)
{
 //...
}
```

---

Essa lista de valores (Disponivel/Não Disponivel/Em Analise) me parece ser requisito do projeto. Um problema é se essa lista tiver que ser alterada:

Certificado: Válido / Expirado / Revogado

Talvez fosse o caso de criá-la com todos os valores possíveis.

> Vale a leitura sobre enum: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22575/69359

Answer (score 1):

**Constantes**

São campos que não podem ser alterados, e funcionam apenas como variáveis de leitura.

Exemplo

```
public const double PI = 3,14;
```

O uso de **enum** costuma ser utilizado quando se trata de opções de resposta fechada por exemplo

```
public  enum Opcao {Sim, Nao}

class resposta
{
    public Opcao Delegado { get; set; }

    public resposta()
    {
        Delegado = Opcao.Nao;
    }
}
```

Desta forma Limita as opções de forma a não causar erros da digitação.
Pode ser utilizado por exemplo para cargos tambem.